# i want to play youtube player in fragment but i dont understand how to extend youtube base Activity with fragment this player correctly working on act

Tags: java, android, api, youtube, youtubeplayer

i want to play youtube player in fragment but i don't understand how to extend youtube base Activity with fragment this player correctly working on activity but i want to play in fragment

```
 VideoPlayer extends YouTubeBaseActivity implements YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener
  youTubePlayerView.initialize(String.valueOf(R.string.youtubeapi), VideoPlayer.this);
 @Override
public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer, boolean wasRestored) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Initialized Youtube Player successfully", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    youTubePlayer.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    youTubePlayer.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);
    if(!wasRestored) {
        youTubePlayer.cueVideo(url);
    }
}
private YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener playbackEventListener = new 
   YouTubePlayer.PlaybackEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onPlaying() 
    }

    @Override
    public void onPaused() {
        Toast.makeText(VideoPlayer.this,"Video has paused", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }




<com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:id="@+id/youtubeplayer"
  />
```

Comment: why are you using YouTube player? you can use a library

Answer (score 0):

You can use extend with YouTubePlayerFragment. You can view the source code https://developers.google.com/youtube/android/player/downloads

public static final class VideoFragment extends YouTubePlayerFragment
implements OnInitializedListener {
...
}

Comment: ok let me check and thank you